# Data in multiple dropdowns

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dropdownbox

I have a form which contains 10 dropdown controls.  Each control will be populated with the same 20 rows of data which are selected from a db table.

What I want to do is ensure that when the final choice is made there are no duplicates.

I could easily just do some error checking when I save the data, but maybe there is a slick way of hiding or graying out the items once they are chosen with javascript.

Has anyone done anything like this?

Answer (score 0):

You could remove items from the other dropdowns when an item is selected in one. So other dropdowns want have that item for selection.